# Not able to detect if a variable representing a string from a csv file is equal to another string

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with 3 columns, the third column contains the type of data that the row is (Training/PublicTest/PrivateTest), and to get that data im running , then i use an if statement to check if the usage is equal to a keyword, and then do some stuff to that row it if its. For some reason it won't detect the usage, and ever row is labeled with a usage, and spelling/capitlization is correct, not sure what to do?

EDIT
Since this csv file is for a machine learning model im currently working, it is huge and it would be much easier if I provided the link: https://www.kaggle.com/ashishbansal23/emotion-recognition. As for the comments regarding printing "usage", etc, i did that and the output was just the word Training, PublicTest, or PrivateTest.

````
    for row in open(path):
        idx = 0
        real_idx = idx + 1
        with open(path, "r") as c:
            emotion, image, usage = c.readlines()[real_idx].split(",")

            if usage == "Training\n":
                train_labels.append(int(emotion))
                imageArr = []
                imageArr.append(image)
                train_images.append(imageArr)
                
    

            elif usage == "PublicTest\n" or usage == "PrivateTest\n":
                test_labels.append(int(emotion))
                imageArr = []
                imageArr.append(image)
                test_images.append(imageArr)
                

            else:
              print("This row was not assigned to any usage!")
            
            idx += 1

    


def load_data():
    return train_images, train_labels, test_images, test_labels


format_data(path)
load_data()```
````

Comment: Show us the first few lines of the input file.

Comment: As a basic debugging step, have you tried printing `usage`?

Comment: as others suggested. best to show a few lines of example data  (can be anonymized / modified as long as it allows to reproduce the problem)
and to show what you expect to get and what you get with your current code.

Use the minimum amount if lines, that allow to show the problem

Comment: one more general recommendation.

If you are not 100% sure, that your csv file will never contain strings with "," or "\n" characters or other quirks it's better to use the `csv` module ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html ) instead of using a simple "," split.

Normally it's also recommended to keep the `with open(..` statement as short as possible. The two if statements don't require the file to be opened, so you can unindent them

Comment: perhaps the reason is, that white space is contained in the lines, and as `split(",")`  would preserve such white space `usage` has leading or trailing white spaces. 

So to add to @John Gordon's comment.

Just add following line for debugging
`print(repr(usage))`

which will show usage, but also clearly indicate leading or trailing white spaces.

Comment: first you should use print() to see what you have in variable - and it is good to display with extra chars `print(">" + usage + "<")` to see if there are some spaces or new lines. OR maybe it uses lower case text.

Comment: thanks a lot for everyone's feedback, turns out the word "Training" was actually supposed to be "Training/n", but I have switched to csv reader as gelonida had mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

> Hi there.
> I would read the CSV file into a string[] like this...

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@csv); // read all CSV lines
int limit = lines.count; // no. of rows
```

> determine the no. of columns based on the "," in the first row

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(",");
string fs = lines[0]; // First string in lines
n = rex.Matches(fs).Count; // how many "," in line
```

> Next, get the number of rows and cols...

```
int rows = limit + 1; // no. of rows
int cols = oc + 1; // no. of cols
public static string[,] table; // The CSV table
table = new string[rows, cols]; // CSV table [rows,cols]
```

> Then break each row in separate values and store'em in the table, that way you can check every item independently

```
string dummy = "";
string ts = "";
int p = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
{
  ts = lines[r].Trim();
  for (int k = 1; k < cols; k++) // break the line into its different parts
  {
    p = ts.IndexOf(","); // position of 1st comma
    if (p == -1)
    {
      if (ts != "" & ts != null)
        table[j, k] = ts.Trim().ToUpper();
      else
        table[j, k] = "X"; // insert an X if no data
      continue;
    }

    dummy = ts.Substring(0, p);
    table[j, k] = dummy.Trim.ToUpper();
  }
}
```

> There, you have an array [n,m] with separate values which you can manage